C# Interface with a base class restriction
I'm using an existing class library that I can't change (Godot if it matters) and have my own classes that extend from the classes in this library.
My classes will not all extend the same class in the library, but they will have a common ancestor class in that library.
I want to write some utility methods that accept some of my classes and call methods on the common base class.
It's easy enough to add an interface for the common methods on my classes, but then I can't also "require" the type to have a common ancestor.
For example I might have the following hierarchy:
Node (API class)
|
+-Node2D (API class)
  |
  +-RigidBody2D (API class)
  | |
  | +-MyClassA : ICommon (My custom class and interface)
  |
  +-Area2D (API class)
    |
    +-MyClassB : ICommon (My custom class and interface)

I then want a method that takes ICommon but requires that it also extends Node2D
Currently the only way I can think to do this is by using generics, for example:
void T MyMethod<T>(T arg) where T : Node2D, ICommon

but that feels very cumbersome, and doesn't work if need to return a different type (which still has the restriction of being a Node2D and ICommon.
It also doesn't work if I want to use a mixed array of classes, for example:
void T[] OtherMethod<T>(T[] arg) where T : Node2D, ICommon

will require the array to be of the same class - I can't have an array with a mix of MyClassA and MyClassB.
Is there a better way to deal with this?

You can actually declare a generic interface
interface ICommon<T> : ICommon {
    public T Instance { get; }
}

and have MyClassA and MyClassB implement it on top of ICommon.
public class MyClassA : Node2D, ICommon<Node2D> {
    public Node2D Instance => this;
}

public class MyClassB : Node2D, ICommon<Node2D> {
    public Node2D Instance => this;
}

this way you can have access to Node2D methods from the Instance property on the interface.
then first method:
ICommon<Node2D> MyMethod(ICommon<Node2D> arg)
 {  
    // arg can be MyClassA
    arg.Instance.Node2dMethod(); // access to methods of Node2D
    return new MyClassB(); // can return MyClassB
}

didn't quite get what you mean or how you are going to use the arrays, but that's the one for them that allows for returning a mix of classes as elements of the interface both for the argument and the return value:
var mixedArray = new ICommon<Node2D>[2];
mixedArray[0] = new MyClassA();
mixedArray[1] = new MyClassB();
var transformed = OtherMethod(mixedArray);
transformed[0] = new MyClassA(); // can still fail if we returned 
// implicitly casted MyClassB[] 
// and not ICommon<Node2D>[] created instance

ICommon<Node2D>[] OtherMethod(ICommon<Node2D>[] arg) {

    arg[0] = new MyClassB();
    arg[1] = new MyClassA();
    
    //return new MyClassB[10]; // works too / but normal array casting issues
    // won't be able to add MyClassA instances to it when returned
    return arg;
}


This looks like a reasonable compromise to the problem I've got. Making the interface generic will also solve the issue with arrays as you show.

Use a Generic Base Class
public abstract class Node2DCommon<T> : Node2D, ICommon where T : Node2D, ICommon
{
    // Your implementation
}

you can use an array of Node2D and ensure they implement the ICommon interface.
public void ProcessNodes(Node2D[] nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        if (node is ICommon commonNode)
        {
            // Call your common methods here
            commonNode.CommonMethod();
        }
    }
}


I'm not sure this matches my requirement. If I do this I would have to get my class to extend this abstract base class - which then means my class only extends Node2D and it wouldn't be an extension of RigidBody2D?
